# Ember js cloning record with relations

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

What I try to achieve: user goes to post/3/edit. Here the form is bound to the model, so it already filled out. And on the top

```
You are editing the post {{model.title}}
```

If the user changes the title it changes dynamic. I don't want this behavior. I want to apply the changes to the record, if user already hit the "Save" button (and everything went right on server side).

my idea:

1. clone the record
2. bind cloned record to the form
3. after hit "Save" the properties of the cloned (and edited) record are applied to the original record.

**Questions**

- Is this the right way to do this?
- Is there something like `record.clone()`, which deep copy the record **with it's relations**?
- Is there a way to apply the changes, like `originalRecord.apply(clonedRecord)`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Ember Data:

An easier approach might be to use the `setupController` hook in your post edit route:

```
// routes/posts/edit.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function (controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    this.controller.set('staticTitle', model.get('title'));
  }
});
```

then in your template:

```
{{staticTitle}}
```

then when you submit the form, reset the static title to the new value after a successful save:

```
// controllers/posts/edit.js
.
.
.
actions: {
  savePost: function() {
    var controller = this;
    var post = this.get('model');
    function onSuccess(savedPost) {
      controller.set('staticTitle', savedPost.get('title');
      //transition somewhere
    }
    function onFailure() {
      post.rollback()
    }
    post.save().then(onSuccess, onFailure);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but "title" was just an example. Imagine the editing form in a modal, and the list of posts in the "background", under the modal. Occasionally you can see all the properties of the post changing. That's why I need some more generic way to clone the record. To set them one by one could be very tedious with 50+ models with 10+ properties each.

Comment: ah ok, well in that case I think you want https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-buffered-proxy

Comment: looks promising, I will take a look at it. Thanks